# Write an iOS App review to disable ads for a day with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ads

I have a "Rate App" popup and I was wondering if there was a way so that if a user clicks "Rate" then I can disable ads for a day. It would serve as an incentive for users to rate the app. Is this against Apple's terms of service?

Heres my code in GameViewController

```
  func rateMe() {
    var neverRate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("neverRate")
    var numLaunches = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches") + 1

    if (!neverRate && (numLaunches == iMinSessions || numLaunches >= (iMinSessions + iTryAgainSessions + 1)))
    {
        showRateMe()
        numLaunches = iMinSessions + 1
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(numLaunches, forKey: "numLaunches")
}
func showRateMe() {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Us", message: "Thanks for using Blocked", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate Blocked", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And I am calling it in GameOverScene with this code:

```
 let controller = self.view?.window?.rootViewController as! GameViewController
        if adLoaded == false {
        controller.showRateMe()
        }
```

Any help on how to implement this would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I'm thinking just making a bool and then setting it to true if they click rate app. Then have a timer that only starts if the bool is true, and it is a 1 day timer that runs a function that will set the bool to false. If the bool is false, then it will display ads.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata):

> Developers who attempt to manipulate or cheat the user reviews or chart ranking in the App Store with fake or paid reviews, or any other inappropriate methods will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

I think offering the user to remove ads by writing a review would fall in the category of paid reviews.
Also I was not able to find a way of detecting an AppStore review.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for that, guess I won't be doing this.